# cannot target 443(8443) on ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot in https using ec2, Route 53.

When I try to set ALB's target groups to register for port 443, it failed in health check.
I opened 443 in security group which apply to ALB, also VPC's network ACL.

So I googled it and found out that "even though 443 is opened, if no one's listening to port 443, then connection to 443 will fail". Reading this comment, I decided to run springboot on port 443.

So I've changed application.properties to use 443 and also shell script file in charge of deploying to use 443. But it didn't work, server couldn't run on 443.

There was no other process on 443,  my firewall setting is opened to 443 too.
After some googling, Someone told me "one some *nix system, 1 to 1024 ports can only be used by root previlege..." So, I changed settings and run my springboot on 8443 , finally succeeded.

But when I try to register target to 8443 it also returns unhealthy, even though I opened 8443 on security group, and there is one process listening to 8443.
I'm kind of lost here.
Is my approach is wrong? what can I do to make it healthy?

I bought domain on other site.
Got SSL Certification from ACM.
Added this SSL as CNAME into Route53 record.
Feeling embarrassed because i'm beginner in aws, also not completly understanding what i am doing.
Right now I'm just thinking making target healthy would solve the problem..
Any references that will help me getting out of this problem would be really helpful. thanks.

Comment: Before getting to the ALB/target groups configurations, have you verified that your application is running properly on port 8443? Run a ```curl``` against your healthcheck route from within the EC2 instance and see if you get the expected response. Please include any errors you've been getting when trying these steps.

Comment: when curl https://sitename :
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about ~~

And curl http://sitename gives me "502 Bad Gateway"

Comment: You can't use your domain name yet because the ALB isn't working. You'll have to use something like ```curl localhost:8443/healthcheckroute``` from within the instance, or if your instance has a public IP you can test with that.

Comment: my healthcheckroute is just '/'. 
So I did curl localhost:8443/ and curl ec2publicIp:8443/ . two of them gave me right html I made. Connection to ec2 public Ip:8443 via web also works.

Comment: Regardless of the actual problem, it is generally ok to terminate SSL on the ALB and use a plain connection from there. This way, you don’t have to deploy SSL certificates on each instance/container.